# Blender 2.8 Armature for Secondlife and Avastar

Tags: armature, compatibility

I'm just starting to learn about making animations with Blender 2.8, primarily for Second Life, and have completed some tutorials for Blender 2.8 that were really very good! Well, as a start at least :)

As I understand it currently the armature for blender to use for Second Life is only provided by the Avastar add-on. That's fine I don't mind signing up for that however it seems that there is currently no release available for Avastar that works with Blender 2.8 One was due last year but the Machinimatrix site has a post from Gaia Clary from Nov 8th 2019 saying it was almost ready but had hit delays due to compatibility issues between Avastar and Blender 2.8. That was of course almost 6 months ago now and I can't find anything else :(

I do realize in these current times all plans are liable to be messed up by things way outside of anyone's control. So what I'm looking for is some advice on my options which I see as follows:

1. Continue to wait for the Avastar version compatible with Blender 2.8 - I'm reluctant to do this as I have no idea in the current climate how long this would be.
2. Regress my Blender 2.82 to Blender 2.79 to use the working Avastar - I'm looking at this as one of the two favorite options at the moment.
3. Switch to another animation authoring tool that doesn't require Avastar - This being the other favorite but having spent days on the Blender tutorials would kinda suck but does have the advantage of avoiding this 'middle man' type relationship between Blender and Avastar.
4. Attempt to use a non Avastar armature for Second Life such as the riggify human meta-rig - Scares the hell out of me as I have no idea how this will work in my target environment!

It's an obstacle I didn't expect and I'm really finding it hard to get much information. So is anyone able to offer me some advice or maybe point out anything I have wrong or missed?  Thanks in advance.

Leni

Comment: Welcome to SE!  SE is a place to ask specific technical questions, and I'm having some difficulty ascertaining the question (about Blender) here.  The gist of the question seems to lie elsewhere (in Avastar's domain).  You might have more luck contacting Avastar directly or checking out BlenderArtist.

Comment: Hi to re-phrase it, I'm hoping to animate in Blender and am looking to find a way of obtaining an armature to use in Second Life. Currently it seems that Blender defers this to Avastar, which isn't working at the moment. So my question is what are my options for getting my Blender animations to work with the Secondlife skeleton. To me that's technical but maybe not so much to this forum, idk this is my first post here :)

Comment: We can help you with the mechanical operation of exporting, but as for meeting Second Life's animation needs and what is going on with Avastar, we cannot help you.